# getimagesize() not working on php 5.6?

Tags: php

I have a php script that gets a base64 string from an ajax request and then I use the getimagesize($image) to obtain its size.
This was working properly on php 5.3 but now that I'm running php 5.6 this doesn't seem to work.

```
$image = $this->input->post('image');
$info = getimagesize($image);
```

Comment: The argument to `getimagesize` is supposed to be a filename, not the contents.

Comment: The thing is that it worked previously in an older version of php. 
I didn't want to save the image that came from this base64 string since I just catch it and the I put it inside a pdf document using TCPDF.

Comment: provide more detailed code

Comment: Was `$image` a `data:` URI? Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

Well as been said by @Barman I guess php 5.6 it's more strict in the use of the getimagesize() function.
I got it working by making a temporary image, pasting it inside my pdf document and then deleting it.

```
    $image = $this->input->post('image');
    $dataURI    = $image;
    $dataPieces = explode(',',$dataURI);
    $encodedImg = $dataPieces[1];
    $decodedImg = base64_decode($encodedImg);

    //  Check if image was properly decoded
    if( $decodedImg!==false )
    {
        //  Save image to a temporary location
        if( file_put_contents(TEMPIMGLOC,$decodedImg)!==false )
        {

            $pdf->AddPage("L");
            $pdf->centreImage(TEMPIMGLOC);

            //  Delete image from server
            unlink(TEMPIMGLOC);
        }
    }
```

Needless to said the centreImage its a custom function inside my pdf class that just centers the image in the new page.

Thanks everyone for the feedback and info, I will dig more into documentation because it's not clear to me how did it work in php 5.3

Just to make it more clear here was the main functions where the getimagesize() was not working.

```
function resizeToFit($imgFilename) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgFilename);
    $widthScale = self::MAX_WIDTH / $width;
    $heightScale = self::MAX_HEIGHT / $height;
    $scale = min($widthScale, $heightScale);
    return array(
        round($this->pixelsToMM($scale * $width)),
        round($this->pixelsToMM($scale * $height))
    );
}
function centreImage($img) {
    list($width, $height) = $this->resizeToFit($img);
    // you will probably want to swap the width/height
    // around depending on the page's orientation
    $this->Image(
        $img, (self::A4_HEIGHT - $width) / 2,
        (self::A4_WIDTH - $height) / 2,
        $width,
        $height
    );
}
```

Comment: There's also [`getimagesizefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) so you don't have to write the image to a file.